# Pass vector<vector<Point> > by reference

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

in OpenCV how can i pass

```
vector<vector<Point> > v
```

By refence to a function.

I tested this and doesnt work:

```
vector<vector<Point> > &v
```

Comment: Show us the complete code that failed.

Comment: That should work, assuming the second code fragment is the function parameter. Could you post the code you tried, and the error message (or describe the problem, if it was a runtime failure)?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  If you get a compile error, include the *exact* error text in your question.  If its a run-time error, what happens when you execute your program?  Showing a bit more code (ideally a full program) would be a big help too.

Comment: Saying that something "doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description. Did it fail to compile, fail to link, do the wrong thing, or what?

Answer (score 4):

If your function take a reference, its prototype should be something like:

```
void func( vector<vector<Point> > &v );
```

Then you just have to pass your vector to this function:

```
vector<vector<Point> > v;    // Create your object
func( v );                   // Pass it to your function
```

The process of passing an argument by reference is explained here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function to take a reference:

```
void f(vector<vector<Point> > &v);
```

and call it with an object of the correct type:

```
vector<vector<Point> > v;
f(v);
```

The function will receive a reference to that object.